# What are valid reasons for establishing a new Minyan?

Tags: tzibur-community, minyan

What are the criteria required for establishing a new Minyan?

Some considerations (not an exhaustive list) for why people might want a new Minyan:

1. Different נוסח (perhaps very few people in the community Davened this different נוסח at one time, but now more people with that נוסח have moved to the community).
2. Personal grievance (shared by the group).
3. Convenience (location and/or scheduling).
4. Too [Heimishe (ie., too much talking)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15506/5).
5. Not Heimishe enough (ie., no socialization, even at permitted times or after Davening).
6. Personal preference (speed, speeches, announcements, Mi SheBerachs, etc.).

Are there hard and fast requirements for establishing a new Minyan?  Guidelines?  If a Minyan is established not in accordance with the requirements/guidelines, does this preclude someone from attending the Minyan, whatever his motivations might be?

Comment: Sounds familiar... is this not a duplicate or something? I haven't time to search at the moment, alas.

Comment: @msh210, It's possible. I may have even asked it before, as this is something I've thought about many times. I did not see it, though.

Comment: Sometimes the existing location simply runs out of space.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/do-not-separate-yourself-from-the-community-what-exactly-is-the-community http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17117/in-a-city-with-many-shuls-how-much-loyalty-do-i-owe-to-the-shul-of-which-i-am-a

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, that one's about the permissibility of switching Shuls. I'm asking about the appropriate way to start a new one. (And whether not following any such rules taints the Minyan.)

Answer (score 6):

Rabbi Yaakov Robinson from Chicago gave a shiur on the topic of breakaway minyanim. You can listen to the shiur [here](http://mikorhachaim.org/shiurim-main/audio/67-breakaway-minyanim). He specifically mentions that he is not discussing the topic of home minyanim (which he says has its own issues), but rather, he is discussing creating a new shul. Here is my summary of the shiur:

The RIVaSh, one of the *rishonim*, says that it is *asur* to prevent someone from building a *shul*. The ReMA *paskens* this as *halacha*. The ReEM, another *rishon* brings as *halacha* that this only applies when the first *shul* does not have enough room for everybody. He argues that it is better for as many people as possible to *daven* together, so a *shul* should only be split up if there is not enough room to hold everyone. Most *achronim* see this as a *machlokes rishonim*.

Everybody agrees that it is not permitted to created a breakaway minyan when it is not done *le-shem shamayim*.  Rabbi Robinson seems to say that a dispute within the *shul* does not constitute a sufficient reason to create a breakaway. He does suggest, however, that personal preferences such as *nusach* could be considered *le-shem shamayim*. This is not necessarily sufficient to create a new *shul*, however.

Also, if the new *shul*'s existence would cause financial or any other type of damage to the original *shul*, everybody agrees that it is forbidden to break away. Rav Moshe Feinstein takes this to an extreme:

A *rav* of a *shul* came to Rav Moshe Feinstein after a group of people broke off from his *shul*. The group had broken away from the original *shul* because when this new *rav* had come, he had changed the *nusach* and the *niggunim* of the *davening*, in such a way which was so confusing to the members of the *shul* that they weren't able to *daven* properly. Also, the *rav* of the *shul* had cursed, scared, and embarrassed members of the *shul* on multiple occasions. The *rav* argued that there had actually only been two times when he had spoken strongly: once when he had to give some *musser* to the congregation, and another time when he said that his words had been misunderstood and he had not intended to be insulting. Furthermore, he said that without the other people remaining with his *shul* it would suffer financially, and not be able to continue operating. Rav Moshe Feinstein said that it was completely *asur* for the group to split off. He explains that just the fact that the break-away would cause financial difficulties for the original *shul* is sufficient to prevent the new *minyan* from breaking off.  It was asked of Rav Dovid Feinstein, the son of Rav Moshe Feinstein, if anything was missing from that story since it seems like the breakaway group had a lot of good reasons for separating. Rav Dovid Feinstein said that nothing was missing from the story and that Rav Moshe held that strongly about causing financial loss.

The *Ksav Sofer* says that it is only permitted to break away in very very unusual circumstances. Rabbi Robinson gives the example of a *shul* taking down the *mechitza* or hiring a female *rabbi* or doing something else that is totally against *halacha*. It seems that many of the *acharonim* and modern *poskim* agree with this opinion.