# Online glossary of Yiddish terms commonly used in shiur

Tags: product-recommendation, yeshiva-school, yiddish, dictionary

A while ago, I saw a one-page glossary of colloquial Yiddish terms that are commonly used in shiur (daily lecture in yeshiva). It looked like it had been photocopied more than a few times, so I think it is likely that it's been widely circulated.

Does anyone know where I could find that, or something similar, available online?

Comment: It wasn't [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1731/5151), was it? ;)

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Conversational_Yiddish

Comment: @Scimonster No, but good try :)

Comment: @Scimonster Those terms are not Yiddish. They seem to be gemoro lashon (Aramaic or Hebrew)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Thanks! It doesn't appear to be *quite* what I'm looking for. I don't need to be able to carry a conversation, but I'll need words like פונקט etc

Comment: @ShmuelBrin The question is terms used in learning Gemoro, not conversational Yiddish

Comment: To clarify - Do you mean strictly Yiddish or are you including "yeshivish", also? Yeshivish contains a mix of English, Aramaic, Hebrew and Yiddish. Is the shiur strictly in Yiddish (other than the Gemarah terms)?

Comment: Is this equivalent to questions about Hebrew language?

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't think so, because there's a focus on yeshiva/shiur, which makes it a Jewish life question

Comment: @DanF I meant Yiddish (I'll be attending a Yiddish shiur this zman, iy"H), but yeshivish would also be useful

Comment: I'll see if I can research. If you're learning in Yiddish, you may have to change your user name to "Shoychit" ;-)

Comment: @DanF good one:) But possibly  Sheikhet if the magid shiur is  Litvish:)

Comment: @user6591 I might actually [have to](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%98%D7%95_%D7%90) change my name to Sheichet :P

Comment: @Shokhet That is actualy exactly what I was thinking of! if your gemara has the פירושממהרצ׳ח in the back (moznaim/vagshal has it) check out his pshat from the vilna gaon.

Comment: @Shokhet I think you're talking about this -- http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38888/1516  -- but it's really bad!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about the Yiddish language are not on topic

Comment: @mevaqesh Didn't we cover this already in the comments above? ...I guess we'll see how the votes come out.

Comment: @mevaqesh IMHO it's not a question about the Yiddish language rather a request for an aid in learning Gemoro.

Answer (score 5):

I got it in camp many years ago and someone tried to fix the words that got cut off it's not perfect and it's not so clear as you mentioned it was photocopied too many times

[image: Yiddish shuir glossary]

Comment: Besides some minor spelling issues (even taking dialect and spelling conventions into account), there are some words there that are incorrectly translated. eg װער means who, not where (but װוּ is correctly translated as where); אַרױס means out, not in (but אַרײַן is correctly translated as in); װיל is want, not because (but װײַל is correctly translated as because); etc.

Comment: @magicker72  I agree with you but that's how I got it I didnt write it

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the exact page you're talking about, but here is something I found that was posted by another Mi Yodeya user on [another Yiddish answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38888/5323):

[image: Useful Yiddish-Shiur Terms]