Suggestions for learning Chassidic Yiddish for Converts and learning chassidus
Due to the vast availability of YIVO textbooks that have slight differences to Hasidic Yiddish - such as the Hungarian “Satmar” dialect - is there any sources one can use to learn it. Duolingo, surprisingly, aids somewhat as it does teach Hungarian dialect but I’d like to be able to speak if for a Torah purpose; learning Satmar Chassidus. Any advice? Such as a useful dictionary or a Shirium.

Satmar isn't big on chassidus as a limud. I think the best way to become integrated into a community is is to spend time within it

Don't think anyone in samar would care what Yiddish you speak. Many very closely affiliated groups with Satmar in Israel speak Lithuanian style yiddish

possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38824/759

In many respects, Hasidic Yiddish is like YIVO's "Standard Yiddish", and they are mutually intelligible to a high degree. Some of the differences that Hasidic Yiddish has include small orthographic changes, inclusion of more "Germanisms" and dialectal terms, and weakening of grammatical cases and genders. Since YIVO Yiddish, and related historical dialects, have substantial resources available, learning the basics of these types of Yiddish may be a good place for a complete novice to start.
To date, there is no comprehensive grammar or dictionary published for modern Hasidic dialects of Yiddish, though many articles have now been published on these topics. There are nonetheless several important resources through which one may learn Hasidic Yiddish dialects.

News sites like Yiddish 24 have both articles and recordings in Yiddish.
Roth's אידיש ווערטער אוצר is a thesaurus of modern Hasidic Yiddish, and is the most comprehensive lexicographical work of the dialect.
Forums like IVelt and Kave Shtiebl reflect more colloquial forms of the language.
Yiddish Wikipedia has some topics written in Hasidic Yiddish, but other dialects, including YIVO כלל שפראך are encountered as well.

In truth, the most effective way of learning this type of Yiddish is through conversing with speakers of Hasidic Yiddish.

The best technique I know uses the following book: https://seforimdeals.com/products/likkutei-sichos-dictionary-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA
It's a tiny dictionary for likkutei sichos (a collection of parsha talks delivered by the Lubavitcher Rebbe) which is a very soft introduction to Yiddish, since it uses lots of Hebrew words where possible. You probably need fewer than 200 words in your working vocabulary to be proficient in sichos.
However, not any volume of likkutei sichos will do for practicing Yiddish. Stick to volumes 15-29, since the others are either in Hebrew or in more complex Yiddish.
So pick up the book I linked above, and then a volume or two of likkutei sichos. Fortunately, if you get stuck, https://projectlikkuteisichos.org/ has tons of helpful translated material and shiurim in English and other languages on volumes 10-23 (as of time of writing, I think they're on 23). You can always find the text of the week's sichos on their site in digital form, but in case you want the book, you can find it here: https://store.kehotonline.com/mobile/prodinfo.asp?number=HRE-LS23
I would also recommend writing notes on the sichos in Yiddish, when you feel that you are able. Just like the sichos themselves, mix as much hebrew or another language as you wish. It's a good way to practice generatively but at your own pace, which is something that's scarce in either text based or discussion based contexts.

The easy-shmeezy guide to Yiddish ( menucha publishers) is a fun way to learn Yiddish. Highly recommend.

Welcome to MI yodeya. This does not answer the question. OP is asking how to learn a certain type of yiddish

@Yoreinu Does the work in this answer teach that type of yiddish?

@DoubleAA it will be extremely hard, if not impossible, to learn any dialect from a book. For example take the word "mein" which means mine, how would you differentiate the pronuciatin of "ei" ofthe hungarian and litvish dialect that will sound different than the Satmar dialect the OP is asking about

@Yoreinu Not a clue, I don't speak any Yiddish. But seemingly a good instructional book will find a way to handle that. (I don't personally know if the work in this answer is a good instructional book, or even a real book. But it prima facie appears to answer the question.)
